# I can understand the function of

Tags: input

In the circuit shown below I can understand the function of the two output diodes 1030 (using for clamping voltage over 3.3 V or reverse voltage), and also I know the function of the two input resistors (voltage divider), 
but I can't understand what is exactly the function of the two capacitors, the amplifier and the 100 Ohm resistor.

[image]

Comment: You've edited out whatever link  you originally had, and at this point your question is quite incomprehensible.

Comment: The opamp is acting as a unity gain buffer. The 100 Ohm resistor and the 1000 pF capacitor act as a single pole low pass filter to reduce noise from the input . As the RC filter is 'tuned" to over 1 MHz it is not obvious what  sort of noise it is targeting.

Comment: A bit more overall description of what you are trying to achiever would be a very good idea.

Answer (score 2):

The related document seem to be [Photovoltaic Power Converter](http://ee.bradley.edu/projects/proj2012/pvc/files/PVC_final_report.pdf). Indeed, it does not describe function of the circuit in detail. It *seems* it scales 24v scale down to 3v3.

In general:

- Resistors 20k/3k is a divider offsetting input DC and ensuring input signal is within (sense) specifications of the input for opamp. You may need to play with values to see the best fit for your application and your opamp;
- top left diode is protection against 3v3 input overshoot;
- opamp is a voltage follower, when output voltage equals to input voltage. By the way, it does not detail + and - inputs, thus output waveform may be same phase or negated phase;
- 100 Ohm resistor has several functions: impedance matching, kind of filtering and protecting right diodes from them being connected directly to opamp output and thus overcurrent through this circuit in case opamp outputs voltage less than 0 (should not be the case as it is powered from 0+5v, but will protect against spikes) and above 3v3 on diode;
- IMHO capacitors are just filtering elements against high frequency noise.
- opamp is used because voltage follower has very high input impedance, thus input voltage will be minimally affected by the operation of the opamp and state of its output.